# How to quote sources in multiple languages in a list of references with APA (and MLA)

Tags: citations, language

The APA Manual of Style covers in detail the issues associated with translating references into other languages. However, it fails to give any answer to my question (just as any resources I have been able to find on the web): **how we should be treating the 'explanatory' elements of references** such as 'Original work published', 'Retrieved', "Manuscript submitted for publication', 'Doctoral thesis', and so on?

Here are two examples of French references:

> Villeneuve, E. (2020). *Éducation* [Thèse de doctorat, Université de
> Tours].
>
> Villeneuve, E. (2010). *Éducation*. Educatio. (Œuvre originale publiée
> en 1922)

When inserting them into a list of references compiled for an **English-language article**, should we keep the 'Thèse de doctorat' and 'Œuvre originale publiée en' elements in French or should we convert them into their English analogues 'Doctoral thesis' and 'Original work published'?

Actually, the same question is valid for MLA, where I fail to find any explicit recommendations.